# Iterating through object array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Please consider X which is an object array. Say object[10].
Elements of the object array represent different values, for e.g. object[1] is studentname, object[2] is birthdate, object[3] is address, and so on.

Following is the way I am trying to pull those values into corresponding variables which I need for further processing

```
string studentName;
string birthDate;
string address;

IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)X;

int counter = 0;
foreach (object obj in collection)
{
   if (counter == 0)
      studentName = obj.ToString();
   if (counter == 1)
      birthDate = obj.ToString();
   if (counter == 2)
      address = obj.ToString();
   ...
   counter++;
}
```

Is this the correct way to get the values of object array into individual variables? Something doesn't feel right.

Thanks

Comment: _"Something doesn't feel right."_ The fact it's in an array of objects to begin with?  This may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `X` is `object[]` then casting it to `IEnumerable` and then iterating over it looks quite redundant.

Just access this array elements by index, like:

```
studentName = X[0].ToString();
birthDate = X[1].ToString();
address = X[2].ToString();
```

Note that null-checking is omitted in the sample, so take care of it if needed. Also you might need some array length check if it is not guaranteed to be 10.